# PyMongo and Flask's Jsonify contains escape slashes

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to make a response using Flask from a Mongodb collection:

```
@app.route('/stories', methods = ['GET'])
def get_stories():
    stories = db.stories.find()

    json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in stories]

    resp = jsonify(data=json_docs)
    resp.status_code = 200

    return make_response(resp)
```

This gets all the items and encodes it into a JSON response, but it looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
   "{\"content\": \"some story here\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5293c34431e20307544db9cb\"}}", 
   "{\"content\": \"some story here\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5293c34d31e20307584c3e6e\"}}", 
   "{\"content\": \"some story here\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5293c57d31e20307a7b40abe\"}}"
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to encode this using single quotes so it doesn't add in the escape strings? Or is there something I'm overlooking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are encoding **twice**:

```
json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in stories]

resp = jsonify(data=json_docs)
```

Now each entry in `json_docs` is a string representing a JSON object.

Remove the `json.dumps()` call:

```
resp = jsonify(data=stories)
```

or use `flask.json.dump()` with a `Response()`:

```
resp = Response(json.dumps({'data': stories}, default=json_util.default),
                mimetype='application/json')
```

This lets you use your `json_util.default` handler on the cursor objects still.

Comment: When I tried this, it gives me a `Cursor not JSON serializable` type error. Which I'm pretty sure has to do with the ObjectID. Any idea how to convert that to json?

Comment: @Chris: Updated, `jsonify()` won't let you specify a `default` handler, so you want to construct the `Response()` object yourself with the return value of `json.dumps()` directly.